# QWebElement has initializer but has incomplete type

Tags: c++, qt, incomplete-type, qwebelement

Whenever I run this code I get an error saying
`QWebElement has initializer but has incomplete type`

```
QWebElement t1 = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("#version");
QString value = t1.attribute("value");
qDebug() << "T1 value:" << value;
value = t1.attributeNS(QString::Null(), "value");
qDebug() << "T1 ns value:" << value;
QVariant v = t1.evaluateJavaScript("this.value");
qDebug() << "Javascript value:" << v.toString(); // ok. returns changed text.
```

I am not filled in on what this error means so any help is much appreciated

Comment: yes, I have webkitwidgets but is webkit and webkitwidgets two different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you include the QWebElement at the header?

```
#include <QWebElement>
```